# Relogio html/javascript não aparece

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tentado fazer um relógio digital aparecer na tela, mas o browser não retorna nada.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Relogio{
            var data = new Data();
            var horas = data.getHours();
            var minutos = data.getminutes ();
            var segundos = data.getseconds();
                if (horas <10 ) {
                    horas= "0"+ horas;
                }
                if (minutos <10) {
                    minutos = "0"+ minutos;
                }
                if (segundos <10) {
                    minutos = "0"+segundos;
                }
    document.getElementByid("relogio").innerHTML =horas+":"+minutos+":"+segundos;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="relogio();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

Sempre abra o console do seu navegador para ver os erros! Tem vários erros de sintaxe no seu código:

- `new Data()` em vez de `new Date()`.
- `getElementByid` em vez de `getElementById`.
- `function Relogio{` deveria ser `function Relogio(){` – ou, melhor ainda, `function relogio() {`
- `getminutes()` deveria ser `getMinutes()`.

Esses erros aparecem em vermelho no console. Deve até ter outros erros do tipo, veja o comentário abaixo, do Guilherme Nascimento, as demais respostas, e revise seu código! De qualquer maneira o console aberto te ajuda a encontrar todos esses erros.

Depois tem um problema de lógica: você tenta pegar um elemento com id `"relogio"`, mas não existe nenhum elemento com esse ID. Troque para `document.body` e o relógio vai aparecer na tela. Adiantando, seu próximo desafio será fazer esse relógio andar sozinho, porque da maneira como programou vai sempre mostrar o horário do carregamento da página.

Comment: Muito bem citado os problemas, também tem um problema que ele escreveu `function Relogio{` quando deveria ser `function Relogio() {` e `getminutes` deveria `getMinutes`, pra resumir, tem muitos erros no script, talvez até algum que eu não tenha notado.

Comment: Realmente, não tinha visto. Fui nos que mais gritaram. Por isso achei importante falar do console.

Comment: Concordo, por isso disse no começo, muito bem citado os problemas, me referia ao console principalmente, só acho que a pergunta já deveria estar fechada, é puramente erro de digitação. Se não fica aparecendo respostas como a do Lucas ali que estaria mais para comentário.

Answer (score 3):

Tenha em mente que o JavaScript é *case sensitive*, ou seja, diferencia letras maiúsculas e minúsculas: `a` é diferente de `A`. Qualquer caractere com o *case* errado causa erro (de sintaxe, não acha um objeto etc.).

**Problemas encontrados:**

**1.** `function Relogio{`

Após o nome da função deve seguir os parênteses: `function Relogio(){`

**2.** `relógio()` vs. `Relogio()`

Note que no `onload` do `body` o nome da função é tudo em minúsculo, e o nome da função inicia-se com "R" maiúsculo. Ou você muda um ou outro para que ambos sejam iguais.

**3.** `var data = new Data();`

A sintaxe está incorreta. O correto é `Date()` (em inglês).

**4.**  `var minutos = data.getminutes ();`

Um problema de *case*. O JavaScript geralmente usa o estilo *camel case* quando um nome de propriedade ou método é composto: `get` + `minutes` = `getMinutes`.

**5.** `var segundos = data.getseconds();`

Mesmo problema do item anterior.

**6.** `document.getElementByid("relogio").innerHTML`

Mais um problema de *case* que causa erro de sintaxe. Lembra do `camel case`? O correto é o `id` começar com "i" maiúsculo: `document.getElementById`.

---

Só faltou o elemento onde você deseja imprimir o relógio. Pelo `.innerHTML` do código, supõe-se ser uma `div` com `id` `#relogio`. Insira-a no `body`:

```
<div id="relogio"></div>
```

Caso queira um temporizador para que o relógio não fique estático, usa-se o `setInterval()` (temporizador ininterrupto que executa uma função no intervalo estipulado em milissegundos).

Como você está chamando a função via `onload`, neste caso, pode colocar o `setInterval()` no fim da função `relogio()`, desta forma:

```
setInterval(relogio, 1000); // 1000 = 1 segundo
```

---

Outro ponto importante (para iniciantes e experientes) é referente à *indentação* do código. Um código bem indentado torna-o mais legível e facilita bastante a manutenção, principalmente em códigos longos (**[saiba mais neste link](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o)**).

---

**Para estudar:**

- **[Variáveis e Sintaxe](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_syntax.asp)**
- **[camelCase](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)**
- **[Funções](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)**
- **[Objetos Date](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)**
- **[setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)**

**Código corrigido:**

```js
function relogio(){
   var data = new Date();
   var horas = data.getHours();
   var minutos = data.getMinutes ();
   var segundos = data.getSeconds();
   if (horas <10 ) {
      horas= "0"+ horas;
   }
   if (minutos <10) {
      minutos = "0"+ minutos;
   }
   if (segundos <10) {
      minutos = "0"+segundos;
   }
   document.getElementById("relogio").innerHTML =horas+":"+minutos+":"+segundos;
   setInterval(relogio, 1000);
}
```

```html
<body onload="relogio();">
   <div id="relogio"></div>
</body>
```

> **E finalmente:** se está usando HTML5, não precisa declarar `type="text/javascript"` no script.

Answer (score 2):

Ajustes realizados

Faltou os () para a function e coloquei o r minúsculo, pois é uma melhor prática function iniciando com letra minúscula e você também está chamando no onload com letra minúscula.

> Relogio para relogio()

Para criar o objeto de data usa-se Date()

> var data = new Data(); para var data = new Date();

O nome das 2 funções do objeto Date estavam errados porque o javascript é case sensitive

> var minutos = data.getminutes (); para var minutos =
>   data.getMinutes();
>
> var segundos = data.getseconds(); para var segundos =
>   data.getSeconds();

O nome estava incorreto porque o javascript é case sensitive

> document.getElementByid para document.getElementById

Acrescentei a div com o id relogio para receber o valor da hora.

```
<div id="relogio"> </div>
```

Segue código ajustado com o que já tinha.

```js
function relogio(){
  var data = new Date();
  var horas = data.getHours();
  var minutos = data.getMinutes();
  var segundos = data.getSeconds();
  
  if (horas <10 ) {
      horas= "0"+ horas;
  }
  
  if (minutos <10) {
      minutos = "0"+ minutos;
  }
  
  if (segundos <10) {
      minutos = "0"+segundos;
  }
  
  document.getElementById("relogio").innerHTML = horas+":"+minutos+":"+segundos;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>teste</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
    
</script>

</head>
<body onload="relogio();">
 <div id="relogio"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Caso deseje para executar a cada segundo você deve utilizar o setInterval conforme abaixo.

```
setInterval(relogio, 1000);
```

Você deve inserir antes da linha , pois deve ficar dentro de script.

Comment: Seria legal se você explicasse o que estava errado e quais alterações você fez pra deixar funcionando. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta se quiser adicionar estes detalhes. Aliás, deixa um comentário me avisando se vc fizer a edição ***=)***

Comment: Boa noite fiz a edição com os ajustes realizados.